# How can ignore spaces with re module

Tags: python, regex

Here is my regex to detect expressions like `{{ value1 | value2 }}`:

```py
p="\{{\{{\s*{tag_key}\s*([^\|\}}]+)\s*\|\s*([^\|\{{]+)\s*\}}\}}".format(tag_key="name")
```

It's totally fine where there are some spaces between `value1`

```
In [1]: re.sub(p, "REPLACED", "content: {{ name |default_value}}")                                                                                               
Out[1]: 'content: REPLACED'
```

**Or**

```py
In [2]: re.sub(p, "REPLACED", "content: {{  name  |default_value}}")                                                                                               
Out[2]: 'content: REPLACED'
```

But what I want is my pattern acts the same either there are spaces or not.

```
In [3]: re.sub(p, "REPLACED", "content: {{name|default_value}}")                                                                                               
Out[3]: 'content: {{name|default_value}}'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn’t working without spaces because you had an extra `([^\|\}}]+)`  that you didn’t need, which was requiring a space to be present. Here’s what I would recommend:

```
p = r"{{\s*" + tag_key + r"\s*\|\s*([^\|}]+)\s*}}"
```

This way the braces `{}` from the Python string format function don’t have a chance to throw you off either.